# How to invoke a pop up window on alternate clicks in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Well, I have been trying to make alternate clicks pop up a new window. ie, if user clicks the first click doesn't invoke any pop up window, every second click, 4th click, 6th click invokes the pop up window., This is the code I tried, But It doesn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
var canClick = 2;
$("body").click(function () {
    if (canClick%2=0) {
        window.open("https://example.com").blur();
        window.focus();}
        canClick = canClick+1;
   });
});
```

Comment: Not solution focused: `function( $ ){` looks odd. I don't think the dollar symbol needs to be there?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. `===` is the equality operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attempt compare `count % 2` with `0` in this line...

```
if (canClick % 2 = 0)
```

... you're using `=`, which assigns values, doesn't compare. To contrast, you have the right use of the `=` operator here:

```
canClick = canClick + 1
```

To actually compare for equality, there are two relevant operators:

- `==` tests for "soft-equality", where `1 == 1` but `1 == "1"` as well
- `===` tests also for type equality, so `1 === 1` but `1 !== "1"` (since their types are `number` and `string`)

You almost always want to use `===`. This would be the working version of your `if` condition:

```
if (canClick % 2 === 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    let count = 0
    $("body").click(function () {
        count += 1
        if (count % 2 === 0) {
            window.open("https://example.com").blur()
            window.focus()
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @Syscall, well, this is a straightforward question and answers,